# PHP regex to match/delete everything between two words

Tags: php, regex

I want to delete everything between #xyzbegin and #xyzend

```
#xyzbegin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/xyz-cache/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/xyz-cache/$1/index.html" [L]

</IfModule>
#xyzend

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

my regex is :

```
'/#xyzbegin(.*)#xyzend/m'
```

I tried this too :

```
'/^#xyzbegin(.*)#xyzend$/m'
```

both doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: `(?<=#xyzbegin)(.*?)(?=#xyzend)`?

Comment: That is matching and deleting everything else in the file

Comment: How so? Can you give us a example file?

Comment: okay, added the full code

Comment: It works, check it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/zYbDgI/1)

Comment: If you are under linux/unix, sed is more appropriate for this kind of task. You can also use perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `s` modifier to match multiline

```
<?php
/**
*/

$in = <<<CODE

#xyzbegin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !^.*(comment_author_|wordpress_logged_in|wp-postpass_).*$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/xyz-cache/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/xyz-cache/$1/index.html" [L]

</IfModule>
#xyzend

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress";
CODE;



echo preg_replace('/#xyzbegin(.*)#xyzend/s','',$in );
```

Comment: weird http://www.noupe.com/development/php-regular-expressions.html says m is for multiline, but s worked.

Comment: `m` multiline if using `^$` , `s` is to match newline with `.` which is your case